# How to use Route component in childrens of useRoutes hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using `useRoutes` hook to setup my app routes because it's cleaner than using `Routes` and `Route` Component. But the problem is that I want to a `Route` component inside one of my pages to show a modal and when I add the `Route` Component it shows this error message:

```
A <Route> is only ever to be used as the child of <Routes> element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your <Route> in a <Routes>.
```

Here is a small version of my code:
App.jsx

```
const routing = useRoutes([{ path: "/myPage", element: <MyPage /> }])
return <BrowserRouter>{routing}</BrowserRouter>
```

MyPage.jsx

```
return (
    <div>
        List of items
    </div>

    <Route path="/myPage/:id" element={<Modal>Detail View</Modal>} />
)
```

I don't want to add the modal route to the useRoutes hook because I have too many modals and it makes the route array out of the control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have routed components that are rendering descendent routes then you'll need to address 2 things.

1. The parent route will need to append the `"*"` wildcard path matcher to its `path` value.
2. All `Route` components can only be rendered as a child of the `Routes` component (*for route matching*) or another `Route` component in the case of nesting routes. Note that nested `Route` components ***is not*** the same thing as rendering descendent routes.

Code:

```
const routing = useRoutes([
  {
    path: "/myPage/*",  // <-- allow descendent route path matching
    element: <MyPage />
  }
]);

return (
  <BrowserRouter>
    {routing}
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

MyPage:

Render the `Route` into a `Routes` component and fix the path. The descendent routes build their paths relative to their parent path.

```
return (
  <>
    <div>
      List of items
    </div>

    <Routes>
      <Route
        path="/:id" // <-- "/mypage/:id"
        element={<Modal>Detail View</Modal>}
      />
    </Routes>
  </>
);
```

[image: Edit how-to-use-route-component-in-childrens-of-useroutes-hook]